# Failed Firebase Functions Emulation

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting up a NextJS app using typescript/firebase/firestore, and emulating functions, firestore, and authentication for development. I have a firebase function that runs any time a user is created.

`firebase/functions/index.ts`:

```js
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { auth, config } from "firebase-functions";

initializeApp(config().firebase);

export const onUserCreate = auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    if (user.email && user.email === "coordinator@example.com") {
        await firestore().doc(`users/${user.uid}`).create({
            isCoordinator: true,
        });

        const customClaims = {
            role: "coordinator",
        };

        try {
            await getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (user.email && user.email === "recruiter@example.com") {
        const customClaims = {
            role: "recruiter",
        };

        try {
            await getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        return;
    }

    await firestore().doc(`users/${user.uid}`).create({
        isRecruiter: false,
    });
});
```

`firebase/functions/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

However, when running `firebase emulators:start` I get the following error:
`!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification`

A similar problem has been discussed on their GitHub under [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5888), but nothing really came of it. I've gone as far as downgrading (as many suggest in the issue discussions), but that hasn't done anything to  help.

What makes this especially strange is that it occasionally works, and I can successfully use the cloud function to do what I want. Does anyone have a clue as to what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: It's failing to find your functions.yaml: https://cs.opensource.google/firebase-sdk/firebase-tools/+/master:src/deploy/functions/runtimes/discovery/index.ts;drc=3182a1b4b00babc9fa8b0a489e6a23a49f965430;l=83

What does your firebase.json look like? Are you starting the emulators from the same directory as firebase.json and not the functions subdirectory?